# lubuntu 12.04 black screen at power-on

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu

Sometimes it happens that at laptop power-on the screen remain black, even if it seems that laptop has been started. In these condition if I digit password (on black screen) the notebook starts session and it works as expected.

Below some information from kernel log, printed more times:

```
Jun  3 22:34:01 Caterina kernel: [  718.126741] init: tty1 main process (1773) terminated with status 1
Jun  3 22:34:01 Caterina kernel: [  718.126788] init: tty1 main process ended, respawning
```

Installed release Lubuntu 12.04 without proprietary drivers. Here is [`lshw`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7546735/) output.